# keyring mysql google cloud

Tags: mysql, encryption, google-cloud-platform

I need to install keyring plugin in mysql running over google cloud and I can not because the user doesn't have `SUPER` privileges. Have anyone had the same situation?

```
mysql < sql_dupm.sql
```

and the error is :

`Error : ERROR 3185 (HY000) at line 98: Can't find master key from keyring, please check keyring plugin is loaded.`

When I tried to install plugin

`mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN keyring_file SONAME 'keyring_file.so';`

`ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use a feature that is not supported.

That may sound like I'm stating the obvious, since it isn't working, but [`SUPER` is definitely not available](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features) so anything relying on it typically would not be, either.  This is not surprising for a managed service.

Additonally, because the keyring_file plugin uses a local file on the server, and you don't have access to the actual server's filesystem, it stands to reason that it is not supported.

I don't find a mention of it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael, Cloud SQL doesn't support SUPER privilege such as the "Unsupported features" section says in the link that he shared. Here is [another link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user) that I found that confirms this behavior.

Additionally, I found out that [MySQL keyring](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keyring.html) is a "service that enables internal server components and plugins to securely store sensitive information for later retrieval.". With this in mind, I figured out in [Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq) some answers that can address your concern, basically your data is encrypted. For a detailed information, look for the questions:

- Is my data encrypted?
- How is encryption managed for data at rest?
- How is encryption managed for data in transit?

Hope the information above help you.